# Java Special Character Handling

Tags: java, encoding, special-characters

I need to send a string to server. That string is having some special characters.

Example,

```
String abc = "ABC Farmacéutica Corporation";
```

When I am sending it, It is converted into, `ABC Farmace@utica Corporation`.

I Tried using UTF-8 encoding. it is giving output as `ABC+Farmac%C3%A9utica+Corporation`

please suggest me how to convert the data in java side.

Comment: URLEncoder.encode(abc, "UTF-8");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *entirely* depends on how the server is set up to receive the string in the first place. Your second example is applying URL-encoding using UTF-8 where required, by the look of things. That *might* be appropriate - or it might not.

If the data is within XML, for example, you shouldn't need to do anything special - whatever XML API you use should handle all of this transparently.

If you can give more details about the protocol you're using to talk to the server, we may be able to help more.

Comment: Ok, I will explain the flow. From JSP I am submitting a page and in java side using springs framework. setting the bean command to another class.

Comment: @Max: That's not very clear I'm afraid. What do you mean by "submitting a page"? Are you saying that the server you're talking to is a servlet? Is the data in the URL or the body?

Comment: passing set of variables in the URL and getting it in servlet class with request.getParameter

Comment: @Max: Okay, finally... in that case you need to investigate how URLs are meant to use percent encoding. It's not clear to me which encoding is used to decode URLs sent in HTTP requests... it could be that the second form you're using is already correct, or you may need to set a particular header. If you can transfer the information in the *body* of the request instead, it'll make things simpler...

Comment: ok, this encode part is what I thought. May be I am wrong. Just check this straight.. Can we pass the special characters like é to database or web-services. If so, how can we handle it?

Comment: @Max: Usually database drivers can handle this with no extra work. Web service proxy code can usually handle it too. But when you've got to supply the URL yourself, you need to know what the service will expect.